# What does this pendant/symbol mean?

Tags: origins, symbolism, celtic

[image: celtiknot?]

This has been antagonizing me for months. When I asked my mom what this was, she said, apart from a bookmark, it was a Celtic knot. But when I look it up, I get anything but this.

What is this? What does it mean? Is it from the Celtic culture?

Comment: Kind of looks like a four leaf clover. maybe stylized as a celtic knot?

Comment: Great question. I have some vague memory of the meaning--weaving was very important pre-modern in agricultural cultures, and typically had associations with the goddess and cycles of life.  (Pagan cultures tend to be preoccupied with generative cycles related to planting/harvesting.)  I found this fairly recent book mentioned in the Wiki references for the Celtic knot page: [*The Language of Ornament*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Language_of_Ornament.html?id=OM9nQgAACAAJ) James Trilling (2001).

Comment: Knot designs appear in [Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_knotting), [Korean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_knots), and [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_knot) cultures as well as [Celtic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_knot). What is the provenance of this bookmark? How big is it?

Comment: It is possibly five to seven centimeters(2-3 inches) in diameter.

Answer (score 5):

It  looks like a kind of square/cross or octagon.

---

**Square / cross** is symbol of [Tetragrammaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton), the four-letter biblical name of the God.

**Octagon** is the ultimate balance between physical and invisible forces. Harmony and perfect equality between matter and spirit. The oneness of the two. The male and female as one. The fully aware humanity. Exhalation of the breath of creation. It is completion of a cycle and infinity of consciousness.